Fresh Windows install, wrong version
Back Story:  Way back when, I bought a Thinkpad W540, it came with Windows 7 Pro.  I did the free upgrade to Windows 10 Pro. This was all connected with my Microsoft account  At some point I also switch to a m.2 sata drive, and have been using that as my system drive for the past 9-ish years on that machine.  It took a catastrophic failure earlier this week. Purchased a replacement, downloaded the Windows 10 install using their Creation Tool. I also tried the route of getting an ISO version as well and reinstalled from that, same results.
Problem: With the fresh install, it's only activated as the Home version.  I can't figure out how to get it to Pro without providing a Product Key, which I never had since it was upgraded during that free switch to 10 period.
How can I get my Pro version of Windows 10 back?
It's too old and doesn't support Windows 11, so that is not an option.

I was not intending on answering my own question, but I just found a solution.
I ended up going to the Microsoft Store on the computer, somewhere I never go, and there it was, the option to install Pro.  No cost or any hoops to jump through, click "Install" and confirm I'm ready to go.  Crazy.

This seems to be a known bug, with a recommendation that users call the Windows Activation dialog from CMD, but your answer is more straightforward.
